# Website refuses to load, but works fine everywhere else. SSL Certificate related

Tags: windows, windows-10, dns, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a computer which has stopped connecting to a website.

Normally this computer would just get rebuilt with the standard image we have for the computer, but there's a lot of bespoke software which requires reinstallation which is always very difficult and can take up to a day.

One website, regularly used, works everywhere else. This computer refuses to acknowledge its SSl certificate and refuses to connect. If I ping the domain, it is unsuccessful. If I add the domain and the IP to the hosts file this is ignored. The message I get from ping is 'General failure'.

We don't have any URL or domain filter, Pihole, or any special rules. there isn't a proxy or squid.

So far I have tried: sfc /scannow, ipconfig /flushdns, netsh winsock reset, adwcleaner, chkdsk /f, cleared cookies and cache multiple times, tried three different web browsers, all to no avail. I have set a static IP address and Google DNS addresses, and very occasionally it works. By the time the user tries it goes back to 'This page cannot be displayed' or SSL certificate errors.

It's a letsencrypt certificate and I have also tried installing the intemediary certificate but no difference.

Are there any other things I can try to resolve this problem?

Comment: Try to log the connection attempt using Wireshark (or other) and try to analyze what happens. If you want us to help, upload it online and let's have the link.

Comment: All those things ("General failure", "unable to ping") happen **long** before the certificate comes into play. If the browser cannot even send IP packets to the server, there's no way it will ever get to the point of requesting the certificate or anything else.

Comment: General Failure only appears when I attempt to ping the website - any other website the ping is successful. In regards to using wireshark, What packets do I need to look for?

Comment: I have the IP address of the website and this pings successfully. I have even added this IP and the website hostname to hosts and it still doesn't resolve. Even created a new admin user and this login has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Malwarebytes.

Even though there are no entries for the website or IP address, and even when it was closed, this program STILL blocked the website. I had to use malwarebytes advanced uninstall tool to remove.

Malwarebytes did not pop up any notification at all.